# Getting "Invalid query" ManagementException

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get system information of the machine which is in domain.
Below is my code for that.

```
ConnectionOptions opt = new ConnectionOptions();
opt.Authentication = System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
opt.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
opt.EnablePrivileges = true;
opt.Username = strUserName;
opt.Password = strPassword;


ManagementPath p = new ManagementPath("\\\\" + strServerName + "\\root\\cimv2");

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(p, opt);

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Architecture FROM Win32_Processor");

ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection results = search.Get();
ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator e = results.GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();

ushort arch = (ushort)e.Current["Architecture"];
```

I am getting exception of invalid query on e.MoveNext() line.This code is running perfectly fine for almost all machine but in some machine it is giving such an exception. I don't know why this exception occur and how to solve it?

Comment: Please post all the relevant code to your question. As is this code cannot be compiled because there is no `e` variable defined anywhere. What is e?

Comment: Steve, by mistake I forgot to add one line in my code which I edited in my que. Can you please look into this? Thanks